# Окно выбора проекта в Андроид Студии

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть ли возможность где-то в настройках выставить так, чтобы при нажатии на ярлык Андроид Студии, у меня появлялось окно выбора проекта(ниже картинка) ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня открывается последний открытый проект.
Перечитал форумы и пересмотрел настройки в АС, не нашел где можно выставить это..

**UPD:**
Не могу найти такую опцию(*Reopen last project on startup*), как предложили ниже.

Захожу в File-Settings-Appearance
и вот скрин, что там есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас печально старая версия, поэтому нужный пункт где-то в другом месте - в новых версиях , на основе IDEA 14, структура настроек другая. Лучше всего обновиться до последней стабильной - AS 1.3, если это по каким то причинам невозможно, то ищите аналогичный пункт где - то в других пунктах настроек, я вот по памяти уже не помню, где оно раньше было, думаю, остальные тоже. :) Возможно в *General* стоит посмотреть ..

Comment: Я так и подумал, что старая версия.. Обновить да, не могу, есть причины:) В настройках нет такого пункта, я облазил все уже)) Вообще я придумал такое решение: просто перед выходом из АС, всегда нажимать File-Close project и тогда будет появляться это окно выбора проекта)) В любом случае спасибо, за участие и советы!)

Comment: Все же где-то там в настройках абсолютно точно есть такой пункт/ Вот [пдфка старого хелпа](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp12/general-2.pdf) к IDEA, там написано, что этот пункт в разделе *General*, как я и предполагал.

Answer (score 3):

Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System settings

[_] Reopen last project on startup (снять галку)

[image: screen]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста.